# How to remove extra spaces in JFrame using GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

When I insert any button or any component in my frame and set the component `gridx` and `gridy` to values `0`, it does not put that component at the starting of the frame instead it put the component somewhere in the center.

How to remove the spaces and put my component at the very starting of the frame?

Following is the code:

```
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("Grigbag layout");

         JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

         GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

         JButton button = new JButton("First button");

         c.gridx = 0;
         c.gridy = 0;
         pane.add(button, c);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the results you are getting and mark on it what you want instead?

Comment: *"How to remove extra spaces in JFrame using GridBagLayout?"*  Start by changing `frame.setSize(1000,700);
     frame.getContentPane().add(pane);

     frame.setVisible(true);` to `frame.getContentPane().add(pane); frame.pack();

     frame.setVisible(true);` ..

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson you can see the image which  i had pasted in the answer below

Comment: Where is the MCVE?  The image should be edited [into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30735524/edit).  Also, a drawing of how the extra space needs to be distributed!  Why am I having to repeat myself?!?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Flow Layout and also add this code

```
frame.pack();
```

as mentioned by Andrew Thompson above

for more :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `frame.pack()`method and remove the `frame.setSize();` method.

Answer (score -1):

frame is using the default layout. Set frame's layout with something like

```
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```